# PHP script to calculate image width and height ratio?

Tags: php, image, resize

I am trying to find a way to calculate an image width/height ratio
to resize it and keep the proportions.

For example, I want to resize a 500x750 image and reduce its width to 350. What height should I use that is proportional to 350?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Javascript.

See this tutorial:
http://www.ajaxblender.com/howto-resize-image-proportionally-using-javascript.html

Using the function the other guy posted:

```
<?PHP

$imagePath = "images/your_image.png";

list($oldWidth, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($image_path); 

$percentChange = $newWidth / $oldWidth;
$newHeight = round( ( $percentChange *$height ) );

echo '<img src="'.$imagePath.'" height="'.$new_height.'" width="'.$newWidth.'">';

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the php function you're looking for: [getimagesize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php)

From the manual:

> Returns an array with 7 elements.
>
> Index 0 and 1 contains respectively the width and the height of the
>   image.

Here's a short example how to work with this for your problem:

```
// get the current size of your image
$data = getimagesize('link/your/image.jpg');

// your defined width
$new_width = 350;

// calculate the ratio
$ratio = $data[0] / $new_width;

// apply the ratio to get the new height of your image
$new_height = round($data[1] / $ratio);
```

...done!

Comment: not quite, i know that function and it is not what i am looking for...I need to know if I resize the width to 350, what should the height be..

Comment: Thats pure math. I'll add a short example how to get there.

Answer (score 1):

You tagged your question with the PHP tag, so assuming you want to use PHP:

To get an image's height or width from an image resource, use `imagesx()` and `imagesy()`.  http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagesx.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagesy.php

To get an image's height and width from an image file, use `getimagesize()`. Items 0 and 1 in the array returned by that function are the width and height of the image. 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php

If you have an image that is 500 pixels wide and 750 pixels high, and you have a container that is 350 pixels wide, you can calculate the ratio by dividing the desired width by the actual width:  `350/500` which is `0.7`.  So to calculate the height, multiply it by that ratio (`750 * 0.7` or `525`).

Comment: I can get the image size....what I am asking is how to calculate...so I guess the formula to perform such task.

Comment: Ah, OK, I've edited my answer to include an explanation of the formula in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

use getImagesize and get the new height by dividing by the aspect ratio.

```
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize("image.jpg");
$aspect = $width / $height;
$newWidth = 350;
$newHeight = $newWidth / $aspect;
```